# Build a scala interpreter in the browser

Tags: scala

My first contact with Scala was through the [SimplyScala tutorial](http://www.simplyscala.com/): You don't need to install anything and can just start to code. After some hours I fell in love with the language...

Years later, I have written a web documentation for a Scala library as a Play Application. It would be cool to build something like SimplyScala and integrate it in the documentation, so that the user can enter Scala commands in the browser and get the result back.

SimplyScala works like [LotREPLS](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/) (old Open-Source-Java-Project with just few LOCs) on the Google App Engine.

**Is is also possible to create something like this on my own server without getting security holes (f.ex. the user should not read files from the server...)?**

I just need the "base" of the Scala language without any imports just like in SimplyScala.

My first idea is to write an own SecurityManager and handle time-outs so that the user cannot consume too much server time. Is there any easier way or an existing open-source project?

Or is it just more rational to advice the user to install Scala and work with the terminal instead of the browser? ;-)

On the Scala homepage is a similar Play-project idea for the [Summer of Code 2012 Scala Projects](http://www.scala-lang.org/gsoc2012#InteractiveDocumentation): but I cannot find any results.

Comment: Not necessarily what you want, but Scala Notebook will soon be open source and covers a lot of the ground you care about. There will be a talk about it next Monday: http://www.meetup.com/ny-scala/events/104791252/

Comment: And now it's actually live! https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook

Comment: Very cool, maybe you want to add this as an answer? But Scala Notebook doesn't care about security, so the user can do all things, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most secure so far is http://www.scala-js-fiddle.com/ ([code on GitHub](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala-js-fiddle)) simply because it does not even run the code on the server, but on the client!

The gotcha is: it's not truly Scala code, it is [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/), which is a dialect of Scala, is still experimental, etc. But it *might* be enough for your use case.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question:

**Scala Consoles, that don't care about security (?):**

- [Scala Web Console](https://github.com/inca/scala-webconsole)
- [Scala IDE](https://github.com/themerius/ScalaIde)
- [Tryscala](http://www.tryscala.com/)

**One web interface which handles somehow security:**

The impressive [Scalakata project](http://www.scalakata.com/), Source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/MasseGuillaume/ScalaKata/).

It's a Lift project that defines an own security manager (see `src/main/scala/com.github.masseguillaume/security`) and handle time-outs (see `src/main/scala/com.github.masseguillaume/service/KateEval.scala`). Now I have to think, if that is secure enough...

Answer (score 2):

https://codebrew.io/ seems to work quite well as Scala REPL

code available at https://github.com/CodeBrew-io

Answer (score 2):

with: `libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value`

### Compiler (`scala.tools.nsc.Global`)

This is the most accurate method to evaluate scala code.
`compileSources` will add a new class in the classloader
[usage](https://github.com/MasseGuillaume/ScalaKata/blob/b80e8acc8bc466980e69220d1c6648cb6507da16/Eval/compile/src/main/scala/com.scalakata.eval/Eval.scala#L13)

### Repl

#### IMain

[usage](https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook/tree/master/kernel/src/main/scala/com/bwater/notebook/kernel)

#### JSR-223

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager
val e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
e.put("n", 10)
e.eval("1 + n") // 11
```

### Reflection Toolbox

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
tb.eval(tb.parse("1+1"))
// res0: Any = 2
```

### Presentation (interactive) compiler (`scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global`)

This is for autocompletion and other interactive features.
[doc](http://scala-ide.org/docs/dev/architecture/presentation-compiler.html)

[usage](https://github.com/MasseGuillaume/ScalaKata/blob/b80e8acc8bc466980e69220d1c6648cb6507da16/Eval/compile/src/main/scala/com.scalakata.eval/Compiler.scala#L13)

Comment: Hm, looks quite promising, I will investigate more into this. (But this also doesn't care about security.)

Comment: Security can be addressed at various level: JVM via security manager, OS via container, etc

Comment: How does this run inside the browser?